# fill in missing values based on unsorted id

Tags: r

I need to fill in the `NA` based on matching ID. However, it's impossible to sort this data.frame so that the relevant `NA` always happen before (or after) the unique ID so I can't use `loc.na`

It's hard to come up with an example that isn't my full `data.frame` but I think this works.. sample data after attempted sort:

```
df
id value col1
1  NA    ABC  
1  2     LMN  
2  3     RGG
2  NA    Z    
3  5     H  
4  7     QRS
```

To look like:

```
id value col1
1  2     ABC  
1  2     LMN  
2  3     RGG
2  3     Z    
3  5     H  
4  7     QRS
```

Or is there a way to use `loc.na` that does not rely on sorting?

Comment: Couldn't you just add a row identifier, do na.locf or whatever to fill, then re-sort?

Comment: How would I add a row identifier in the right order? I don't know if the `NA` happens before of after. I  resorted my sample data to better demonstrate this.

Comment: `df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(value = na.locf(value))` seems to work regardless if you're in dplyr world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df  <- read.table(header = TRUE,
                 text = "id value col1
                  1  NA    ABC  
                  1  2     LMN  
                  2  3     RGG
                  2  NA    Z    
                  3  5     H  
                  4  7     QRS  
")
```

First you could order the data frame, for example with the package data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setorder(df, id, value)

> df
  id value col1
1  1    NA  ABC
2  1     2  LMN
4  2    NA    Z
3  2     3  RGG
5  3     5    H
6  4     7  QRS
```

If you want it to be after, you could just setorder(df, id, value, na.last=T). 
Finally you can replace NA's:

```
df$value[is.na(df$value)] <- df$value[which(is.na(df$value))+1]
```

And then sort it again:

```
setorder(df, id, col1)

> print(df, row.names = F)
 id value col1
  1     2  ABC
  1     2  LMN
  2     3  RGG
  2     3    Z
  3     5    H
  4     7  QRS
```

Comment: Perfect! I know the example didn't show this, but what if there's more than one `NA` value per `id`?

Comment: @RafaelMartins Well, then I guess another approach needs to be taken :)

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't this work ?

```
matching_table <- unique(df[,c("id","value"))
new_df <- merge(df[,-2],matching_table,all.x = TRUE)
```